# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object, WHY?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use a WebApi to get a list of Employees from my data base, using this code:
This is the code of my client MVC Application:

```
        string u = "http://localhost:1411/api/EmployeeAPI";
        Uri uri = new Uri(u);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        Task.WaitAll(response);

        HttpResponseMessage resposta = response.Result;

        var msg = resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Employee[] employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(msg);

        return View(employees);
```

And this is the code of my WebAPI:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

But this error keeps popping up and I can't understand why:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'DataAccess.Employee[]' because the type requires a JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the
>   deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Message', line 1, position 11.

My Employee Class:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public byte[] rowguid { get; set; }
        public System.DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Json output I'm not really sure how to get it

The msg variable content:

My msg variable returns

"{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\",\"StackTrace\":null,\"InnerException\":{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProductSubCategory_9EC9A3706390DE6A3B51F713F0DDAC2162AFB5B3FAB8F8587C9A865333A7729A'. Path '[0].Products[0].ProductSubCategory.ProductCategory.ProductSubCategories'.\",\"ExceptionType\":\"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__c()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)\"}}"

Comment: First thing to do: separate the WebAPI part from the client part; fetch the JSON and check whether or not it makes sense. If it does, hard-code it into a small client program to isolate *just* this problem.

Comment: Can you post the JSON output that cannot be deserialized?

Comment: Show us your JSON and your `Employee` class

Comment: If seems that the JSON returned is a representation of a single object  not array of employees.

Comment: I updated the post so it has the employee class....the Json i not sure where to get it

Comment: for the JSON, can you give us the value for your 'msg' variable?

Comment: I updated the post so it has the variable "msg" content

Comment: Will somebody help me?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to stop that error from occuring is:

In your WebApi project go to the App_Start folder and add to the WebApiConfig this four lines of code:

```
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

and make sure you have instaled the Json nuget package

Answer (score 6):

Read the error;

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'DataAccess.Employee[]' because the type requires a JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

```
 var msg = resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

 Employee[] employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(msg);
```

You need to make sure above "msg" is an actual JSONArray.

```
{ "key" : "Value" }
```

is a JSONObject,

```
[{ "key" : "Value" }]
```

is a JSONArray.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i do that, please? I'm really new to MVC and C# and i'm very confused with this

Comment: the problem is that I don't have any console aplication in this project. This is a "school" project...and with the exact same code, another classmate off mine could deserialize the json whithout any problem

Comment: you need to make sure http://localhost:1411/api/EmployeeAPI is returning the right data to you. Your code works as intended, it's parsing an array of Employee JSON objects into Employee c# class. If this isn't what you wanted then you need to look at making it a non-array then.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted....I'm just not sure why the localhost:1411/api/EmployeeAPI isn´t returning an IEnumerable...perhaps is something to do with my data base?