# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object, why does this error?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use a WebApi to get a list of Employees from my data base, using this code: This is the code of my client MVC Application:

```
string u = "http://localhost:1411/api/EmployeeAPI";
Uri uri = new Uri(u);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

Task.WaitAll(response);

HttpResponseMessage resposta = response.Result;

var msg = resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Employee[] employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(msg);

return View(employees);
```

And this is the code of my WebAPI:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
return db.Employees.AsEnumerable();
}
```

But this error keeps popping up and I can't understand why:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) 
into type 'DataAccess.Employee[]' because the type requires a 
JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either 
change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized 
type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, 
not a collection type like an array or List) 
that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize 
from a JSON object. Path 'Message', line 1, position 11.
```

My Employee Class:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte[] rowguid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
 }
}
```

My JSon

```
"{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\
"ExceptionMessage\":\"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.\",\
"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\",\
"StackTrace\":null,\
"InnerException\":{\
"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\
"ExceptionMessage\":\"Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProductSubCategory_9EC9A3706390DE6A3B51F713F0DDAC2162AFB5B3FAB8F8587C9A865333A7729A'. 
Path '[0].Products[0].ProductSubCategory.ProductCategory.ProductSubCategories'.\",\
"ExceptionType\":\"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException\",\
"StackTrace\":\" 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n 
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__c()\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)\"}}"
```

Comment: I think you got the `r` tag wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to use List<T> instead of [] and in you api List instead  IEnumerable ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object, WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126675/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-why)

Comment: I post my JSON , please check

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like the problem is with the subcategory field or property of the Product class.

Comment: but how i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you go through the exception message, you might be able to drill down the problem.

Exception message is saying that a self referencing loop is detected. Can you look into / share the Model ==> **Products[0].ProductSubCategory.ProductCategory.ProductSubCategories'**

```
"ExceptionMessage\":\"Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ProductSubCategory_9EC9A3706390DE6A3B51F713F0DDAC2162AFB5B3FAB8F8587C9A865333A7729A'. 
Path '[0].Products[0].ProductSubCategory.ProductCategory.ProductSubCategories'.\",\
"ExceptionType\":\"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException\",\
"StackTrace\":\" 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
```